# Checkbox is not Checked as checkboxes are working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html code. input field is dynamic from database that's why I write code like this

```
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none" value="1">Option 1
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none" value="2">Option 2
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none" value="3">Option 3
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none" value="4">None
```

Here is jquery code

```
<script>
    function uncheckOthers(ele) {  
    if(ele.checked && ele.value == "4") { // check #none is checked and has its value 4
    ele.checked = false;
        $('.example').prop('checked', false);// Uncheck all the checkboxes with class 'example'
    }
};
</script>
```

Here is [**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/phcrh2ds/13/)

**Issue**

When I checked checkbox which value is **2** and **3** then when I checked checkbox which value is **4** so **2** and **3** are unchecked but value **4** checkbox is not checked. Its showing like that unchecked

I removed this line from jquery code. In fiddle its working perfectly but in my html page is not working good way

```
ele.checked = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle and your posted code are not the same. I think your code in fiddle is better and easier to fix. You can do something like:

```js
function uncheckOthers(ele) {
  if (ele.checked && ele.value == "4") {
    $('.example').prop('checked', false);   //If none is clicked. Uncheck all example
  } else {
    $('.termcls').prop('checked', false);   //Else, Uncheck termcls since one of the example is clicked
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" class="example" name="Option 1" value="1">Option 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" class="example" name="Option 2" value="2">Option 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" class="example" name="Option 3" value="3">Option 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" class='termcls' name="None" id="none" value="4">None<br>
```

---

One your posted code, you can use `:not` selector to exclude the none(option 4) option.

```js
function uncheckOthers(ele) {
  if (ele.checked && ele.value == "4") {
    $('.example:not([value="4"])').prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $('.example[value="4"]').prop('checked', false);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none1" value="1">Option 1
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none2" value="2">Option 2
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none3" value="3">Option 3
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none4" value="4">None
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Eddie now its working perfect whats I needed thanx once again

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: And btw, I forgot to point out that id should be unique. On your posted code all checkboxes have `none` id. You also need to change that.

Comment: Yeah I knew it id must be unique. Actually I getting values from database using loop that's why I need to resolve this issue by value

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You want the `None` checkbox to be checked after you check it, so use `ele.checked = true;`
- When *other* checkboxes are checked, you should uncheck the `None` checkbox

So, try this (no jQuery required):

```js
const noneCheckbox = document.querySelector('#none');
const examples = [...document.querySelectorAll('.example')];
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox') return;
  if (e.target === noneCheckbox) {
    examples.forEach(example => example.checked = false);
    return;
  }
  const someChecked = [...document.querySelectorAll('.example')].some(({ checked }) => checked);
  if (someChecked) noneCheckbox.checked = false;
  else noneCheckbox.checked = true;
})
```

```html
<form>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 1" value="1">Option 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 2" value="2">Option 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 3" value="3">Option 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" class='termcls' name="None" id="none" value="4">None<br>
</form>
```